# Проблемка не большая discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Всем привет, у меня не большая проблема, нашла код на просторах интернета, но он не работает, бот включается ошибок не пишет а ембед не присылается
вот код:

````
async def verif(ctx):

    emb = discord.Embed(
        description =
        f"""
        Необходимо пройти верефикацию(Нажав на кнопку ниже), чтобы получить доступ к каналам.
        """,
    )
    emb.set_author(name = 'Привет, ты на сервере ⚡ Cascade ⚡')

    row = ActionRow(
        Button(
            style = ButtonStyle.gray,
            label = '',
            custom_id = 'verif_button'
        )
    )
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, components = [row])

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(inter):

    res = 'Вы успешно верифицировались!' # ваш вывод сообщение что человек получил роль
    guild = bot.get_guild(inter.guild.id)

    if inter.component.id == "verif_button":
        verif = guild.get_role(864163458744582145)
        member = inter.author
        await member.add_roles(verif)
        await inter.reply(res, ephemeral = True)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы правильно вставили код в впорос, то скорее вссего Вам просто нужно добавить `@bot.event` перед функцией `verif` и всё должно зароботать. Данный декоратор отвечает за то что функция которая помещенна в него будет являться коммандой боту. Если у Вас не получилось исправить код, то будьте добры отправить сюда ВЕСЬ исзодный код(без тоекена) и я посмотрю!

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, сейчас проверю

Comment: ничего не получилось(((

Comment: сейчас скину фулл код

Comment: а лучше пойдемте в Discord?

Comment: svell#9317 пишите

Comment: Я отправил заявку, никнейм такой же как и на форуме, только другим шрифтом. Завтра спишееммся и я попробую Вам помочь

Comment: Извините, я Вам помог, могли бы вы нажать галочу слева от моего ответа, это очень поможет мне в продвижении на форуме